# can't get jqPlot chart to show line from Variable

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to plot some points in my webApp, so I'm trying this:

```
var plot10 = $.jqplot ('heightChartDiv', [[3,7,9,1,5,3,8,2,5]]);
```

and it works fine, I this exact chart [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php)

but when I take it out, to give it a value, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var serie1 = [[3,7,9,1,5,3,8,2,5]];
}

function doGraph(){
 var plot10 = $.jqplot ('heightChartDiv', serie1);
}
```

It doesn't work. am I declaring the variable wrong? please HELP!

~Myy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable scoping is all off.  The variable `serie1` has local scope to the anonymous function defined in `$(document).ready` event.  Read up on javascript scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/).

Perhaps something like this:

```
// the document ready will fire when the page is finished rendering
// inline javascript as you've done with your doGraph will fire as the page renders
$(document).ready(function(){

  // first define graph function
  // make the series an argument to the function
  doGraph = function(someSeries){
    var plot10 = $.jqplot ('heightChartDiv', someSeries);
  }

  // now call the function with the variable
  var serie1 = [[3,7,9,1,5,3,8,2,5]];
  doGraph(serie1);

}
```

**EDITS IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

See this below example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var a = 1;

  someFunc = function(){
    var b = 2;
    alert(a);                   
  }

  someFunc();  // this works
  alert(b);  // this produces an error

});​
```

Here the variable a is considered global to the function someFunc.  A variable declared in someFunc, though, does not persist outside of it.

Comment: Well it doesn't make any sense then, because I have an ajax call that sets a variable with a value in the $(document).ready(function(){  and when I call the doGraph() it gets the correct values. I just don't get why it would be any different. ( not saying you are wrong, just that it's not very intuitive)